# Need explanation with Icecast URL authentication

Tags: drupal-7, icecast

Foreword: I am stuck due to poor coding skills and a lack of understanding of the details of the URL authentication. I am not a coder but an amateur who usually get by with a little help from Google.

Challenge 1:

I am trying to set Icecast up in such a way that the audio stream can only be heard when you log in to my website. The method is called URL authentication by Icecast. Here is the link to the official documentation:

https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.0/auth.html

My problem: I understand that I have to integrate certain queries in the `icecast.xml` that are then answered by the player on my website. Unfortunately, I don't know where to integrate these codes. In a file in the webroot? In the header of the player page?

Challenge 2:

Another thing is that the player is working, but when I hit the pause button and restart the player 10 minutes later the song picks up there I paused the player even though the radio stream is already 2 titles ahead. So the cover art does not match the audio.

I guess that also has something to do with certain tweaks in the `icecast.xml`. Again ... I don't know how to add these tweaks and how to address them on my website (same issue as with the authentication).

Due to royalty issues, my website is behind a firewall for the time being.

Can anyone shed some light on my questions?

I included the code of my `icecast.xml` and of the `iFrame` that contains the player.

Best wishes, 
Paul

This is the `iFrame` that contains the Drupal website and the HTML5 player:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
            background: #333333;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            }
   iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 92%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            border: none;
            display: block;
        }
  </style>
<body>

<?php
print('<iframe id="drupal_site" src="http://test.zoootradio.com" height="92%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>');

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.

print('<audio id="player" controls>');
print('<source src="http://192.168.2.50:8000/zr.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">');
print('</audio>');
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my icecast.xml file:

```
<icecast>

<location>Earth</location>
<admin>icemaster@localhost</admin>

<limits>
    <clients>15</clients>
    <sources>1</sources>
    <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
    <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
    <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
    <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>

    <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>

    <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
</limits>

<authentication>
    <!-- Sources log in with username 'source' -->
    <source-password>XXXXXXX</source-password>
    <!-- Relays log in with username 'relay' -->
    <relay-password>XXXXXXX</relay-password>

    <!-- Admin logs in with the username given below -->
    <admin-user>XXXXXXX</admin-user>
    <admin-password>XXXXXXX</admin-password>
</authentication>

<hostname>192.168.2.50</hostname>

<!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
<listen-socket>
    <port>8000</port>
    <!-- <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address> -->
    <!-- <shoutcast-mount>/stream</shoutcast-mount> -->
</listen-socket>

<http-headers>
    <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
</http-headers>

<mount type="normal">
    <mount-name>/zr.mp3</mount-name>
    <authentication type="url">
        <option name="stream_auth"     value="http://test.zoootradio.com/player"/>
    </authentication>
</mount>

<fileserve>1</fileserve>

<paths>
    <!-- basedir is only used if chroot is enabled -->
    <basedir>/usr/share/icecast2</basedir>

    <!-- Note that if <chroot> is turned on below, these paths must both
         be relative to the new root, not the original root -->
    <logdir>/var/log/icecast2</logdir>
    <webroot>/usr/share/icecast2/web</webroot>
    <adminroot>/usr/share/icecast2/admin</adminroot>
    <!-- <pidfile>/usr/share/icecast2/icecast.pid</pidfile> -->

    <alias source="/" destination="/status.xsl"/>
    <!-- The certificate file needs to contain both public and private part.
         Both should be PEM encoded.
    <ssl-certificate>/usr/share/icecast2/icecast.pem</ssl-certificate>
    -->
</paths>

<logging>
    <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
    <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
    <!-- <playlistlog>playlist.log</playlistlog> -->
    <loglevel>3</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
    <logsize>10000</logsize> <!-- Max size of a logfile -->
    <!-- If logarchive is enabled (1), then when logsize is reached
         the logfile will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.DATESTAMP,
         otherwise it will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.old.
         Default is non-archive mode (i.e. overwrite)
    -->
    <!-- <logarchive>1</logarchive> -->
</logging>

<security>
    <chroot>0</chroot>
    <!--
    <changeowner>
        <user>nobody</user>
        <group>nogroup</group>
    </changeowner>
    -->
</security>
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1 - "URL auth"

Your `icecast.xml` does not contain any  definition, so you don't have URL-auth configured.

What are you really trying to achieve?

## 2 - pause

Streams can't be paused, don't try to do it, it will break things. If you stop a stream, make sure that you do it in a way that makes the browser actually drop the connection.

Also you should always use a 'cache buster' or other way to ensure that the browser does *not* try to use cached stream content. (See my other answers on related topics here)

Comment: I edited the "mount" section in the Icecast configuration file (see above) to enable URL-auth. So far I did not notice any change. 

Do I have to include something is the iFrame that contains my website and the HTLM5 player (see above) to make this work?

Comment: As for number 2, with stopping I meant clicking on the pause button of the HTML5 audio player. I assumed that the stream will continue, but the player will pick up the stream where it paused. So I guess it must use some kind of caching even though the headers on the iFrame said no t to cache. So I added another set of "no cache" variables in the php part of the iFrame.